# Canaon G3200 worked great right after installed but

Tags: 20.04

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 and it works great.  I bought a new Canon G3200 printer and installed it.  I printed a picture with it with no problem but now when I try to print anything, the job goes to the printer but then I get the message "printer stopped".   Any thoughts?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20. Do you mean 20.10 or 20.04?

Comment: 20.04 says the terminal